# nginx ssl rejecting non matched server_name requests

Tags: ssl, nginx, sni

```
server {
        lerver {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  proxy.test.com;

        ssl_certificate      sni.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  sni.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       443 default_server ssl;
        server_name  test.com; 

        ssl_certificate      test-cn.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  test-cn.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

      }
```

I want configure nginx with ssl to honor SNI requests (server_name directives in ClientHello from clients), reject handshakes with mismatched server_name SNI requests and serve default certificate for non SNI requests (ClientHello with no server_name directives).

With above configuration, I can make nginx to honor SNI request for proxy.test.com. But for ClientHello with SNI request as invalid-domain.com and for ClientHello with no SNI request, default server block is used. How do I make nginx to reject the SNI requests for invalid-domain.com while at the same time having a default server block for non SNI requests?

Answer (score 4):

I came across this newer feature of nginx that will drop requests prior to even sending a server_hello if the server_name requested does not match what you have listed in your server directive. I think this would help accomplish what you're looking to do. The below configuration should drop all requests to 443 unless the SNI matches proxy.test.com.

```
server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
}
server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  proxy.test.com;

        ssl_certificate      sni.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  sni.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
 }
```

Link to docs.

[ssl_reject_handshake](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_reject_handshake)